# Dell Inspiron 1545 with Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, networking

I've installed Ubuntu on a Dell Inspiron 1545 and I'm not sure how to connect to my router wirelessly. It's asking for some information that I haven't seen before. 
In a window titled, Editing Wireless conenction 1 under the Wireless tab I see:

SSID (i know what this is)
Mode
BSSID
Device MAC Address
Cloned MAC Address
MTU

If any of you could help me I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

In general, you only need to supply the SSID and security settings to connect.

For your Inspiron 1545, you need to install the Broadcom wireless drivers.  Open up the Software Sources application click on the tab "Additional Drivers" in the window that appears.  You should see a list of available drivers.  Install the Broadcom wireless driver.  You may need to restart your computer, but wireless should work after that.

If the additional drivers fail, see:

[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

Comment: I filled out the SSID and the security settings. I'm out of the box new to linux, but how do i connect to the wireless now?

Comment: Do you see the network icon in the top right corner?  It is near the clock and volume control.  Click on it and you should see your network.

Comment: I see: Wired Network (greyed out)
disconnected (greyed out)
VPN Connections
Enable Networking (its checkec)
Connection information (greyed out)
Edit Connections

Comment: What type of wireless adapter are you using?  Is it built-in to the computer or do you have another adapter?

Can you also post the output of `iwconfig`?

Comment: built into the computer. how do i give you the output using iwconfig? Terminal?

Comment: Yessir, I just need to see if your adapter is being detected or not.

While you're at it, can you post the output of `lspci`?

Comment: using Terminal it says
etho  no wireless extensions.

lo    no wireless extensions

Comment: 1spci says

no command '1spci' found, did you mean: command '1spci' from package 'pciutils' (main)
1spci:command not found

Comment: Can you post the output of `lspci -nn`?

Comment: 1spci -nn says no command '1spci' found, did you mean: command '1spci' from package 'pciutils' (main) 1spci:command not found

Comment: lspci not 1spci.

Comment: No command '1spci' found, did you mean:
Command 'lspci' from package 'pciutils' (main)
1spci: command not found
orisci@orisci-Inspiron-1545:~$ 1spci -nn
No command '1spci' found, did you mean:
Command 'lspci' from package 'pciutils' (main)
1spci: command not found
orisci@orisci-Inspiron-1545:~$ lspci

Comment: 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)

Comment: 00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)

Comment: 00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)

Comment: 00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)

Comment: thats the end of it

Comment: Ah just as I thought, you need to install the Broadcom drivers.  See my updated post.

Comment: Where's your updated post?

Comment: I just updated my answer. :)

Comment: Alright I see your answer, but since i'm just this new... how do i get to Software Sources?

Comment: Click on the Ubuntu button in the top left corner of the screen and type Software Sources.  Click on the icon when you see it in the dash.

Comment: okay when i try that and select Using broadcom then hit apply it will revert to Do Not use the device, even after restart.

Comment: In the 'Ubuntu Software' tab, is the Proprietary drivers box checked?

Comment: the checkbox on it is checked, yes

Comment: See my updated post.  You may need to install the drivers using the terminal with the link I have provided.